# Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/zv/vwwhcqfs4xj_9b09bbs1c3cm0000gn/T/pip-build-TZP2Ho/pyquil/

Tags: python, macos, installation, pip, setuptools

I'm trying to run this in Terminal:

```
pip install pyquil
```

But then this error comes up:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/zv/vwwhcqfs4xj_9b09bbs1c3cm0000gn/T/pip-build-8VPMQz/pyquil/
```

I've read through many other threads with the same problem and tried some solutions, but still no luck.

Attempted Solutions:

1. Add this to bash profile:

   export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

   export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
2. Updating pip/setuptools
3. Using ez_setup

I'm trying to follow this, and have the prerequisites: http://pyquil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/start.html

Any ideas?

Comment: The message you posted (`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in ...`)  is a generic error message and does not help at all. Post the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

Try upgrading your pip & pip setup tools and then try,

```
sudo pip install pyobjc-core
sudo pip install pyobjc

sudo pip install --upgrade pip

sudo pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Then

```
sudo pip install pyquil
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem on a MacBook Pro (2019). I was able to fix it by running

`python3 -m pip install [package]`

In your case that would be

`python3 -m pip install pyquil`

The reason is that sometimes just invoking `pip` directly (e.g., outside a virtual environment) will point to the system's installation, which is likely associated with Python 2.7 (the standard installation on Macs). Hence the outdated `python setup.py egg_info...` syntax. More recent PyPI packages use the `pyproject.toml / setup.cfg` approach, and these days `setup.py` is deprecated.

On my system, running `which pip` yields `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/pip`, and running `pip install pyquil` will fail the same way it did for you. By prepending `python3 -m` to this command, the problem is fixed.

Of course, the best practice would be to create a virtual environment, activate it, and then use pip from within that environment to install your package. I.e.:

```
python3 -m venv myenv
source myenv/bin/activate
pip install pyquil
```